# What is the bibliography style similar to 'jneurosci' but without italics for journal field

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have been struggling to write my reference list according to the following style given by journal of ERE:

> Smith J, Jones M Jr, Houghton L et al (1999) Future of health insurance. N Engl J Med 965:325–329

I used `\bibliographystyle{jneurosci}` and it looks very similar!
but it came out with some italics as shown here

[image]

Is there another style that I should use or I should learn to do it manually somehow in order to get an author-year citation that I want?

Comment: The template provided by the "Environment and Resource Economics" journal site suggests using the `spbasic`, `spmpsci`, or `spphys` bibliography styles.

Comment: @Mico  
Yes"Environmental and Resource Economics". Thank you very much!! Now I can use spbasic style :)

Answer (score 1):

I infer that "ERE" is short for "Environmental and Resource Economics". The journal's website provides a link to a template that suggests using one of the following three bibliography styles: `spbasic`, `spmpsci`, or `spphys`. All three bibliography styles may be downloaded from various Springer Verlag sites.

Using the `spbasic` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package yields the following look, which indeed looks like what you're after.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{schaefer:54,
    author  = "Schaefer, Milner B.",
    year    = 1954,
    title   = "Some aspects of the dynamics of populations 
               important to the management of the commercial 
               marine fisheries",
    journal = "Inter-American Tropical Tuna Commission Bulletin",
    volume  = 1,
    number  = 2,
    pages   = "23-56",
} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
%ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svmultt1/styles/spbasic.bst
\bibliographystyle{spbasic} 

\begin{document}
\cite{schaefer:54}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```